# Connection error в вк боте

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, connection

Язык:Python

Я сделал бота для вк. Сначало все было отлично бот работал, но на следующий день бот крашнулся.

Ошибка:

```
  File "Vk_bott.py", line 87, in main
    longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)
  File "C:\Users\antonio_cra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-
packages\vk_api\longpoll.py", line 517, in __init__
    self.update_longpoll_server()
  File "C:\Users\antonio_cra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-
packages\vk_api\longpoll.py", line 531, in update_longpoll_server
    response = self.vk.method('messages.getLongPollServer', values)
  File "C:\Users\antonio_cra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-
packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 606, in method
    values
  File "C:\Users\antonio_cra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-
packages\requests\sessions.py", line 581, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\antonio_cra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-
packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\antonio_cra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-
packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\antonio_cra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-
packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.vk.com', port
=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /method/messages.getLongPollServer (Caused
 by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x
0C0F7DB0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo faile
d'))
```

И эта ошибка переодически повторялась через 1-2 дня. Я не могу понять из-за чего она и как ее решить?

Код подомный моему:

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
token = ""
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk)
for event in longpoll.listen():
  if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
    if event.to_me:
       if event.text == "привет":
         vk.messages.send(user_id=event.user_id, random_id = get_random_id(), message= 'привет')
       elif request == "пока":
          vk.messages.send(user_id=event.user_id, random_id = get_random_id(), message='пока')
```

P.S

try except не помогают

Comment: Проблемы с интернет соединением: `Max retries exceeded, failed to establish a new connection` (превышено максимальное число повторных попыток, не удалось установить новое соединение). Может быть как с Вашей стороны, так и со стороны ВК. Просто перезагружайте скрипт или переходите на `Callback API` (с контролем доставки).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, просто я бота ставил на pythonanywhere и он все равно крашится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переопределите класс VkBotLongPoll и используйте его

```
class MyVkBotLongPoll(VkBotLongPoll):
    def listen(self):
        while True:
            try:
                for event in self.check():
                    yield event
            except Exception as e:
                print('Longpoll Error (VK):', e)
```

Создайте сущность нового класса

```
def __init__(self):
    ...
    self.longpoll = MyVkBotLongPoll(vk_session, group_id=self.group_id)
```

Используйте её

```
def listen_longpoll(self):
    for event in self.longpoll.listen():
    ...
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: Не совсем понял как этим пользоватся, можете обьяснить по подробней?

Comment: Поправьте вопрос, покажите, как у вас сейчас работает бот

Comment: Все, поправил вопрос

Comment: 1. Объявляете класс, который я описал выше
2. Изменяете код, вместо longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk) пишете longpoll =MyVkBotLongPoll(vk)

Всё. Этот класс враппит обычный VkLongPoll, обрабатывая исключения вк, которые периодически проскакивают

Comment: Большое спасибо, все работает. Если код не остановится в течении 4 дней отмечу ваш ответ как ответ